# Notepad++ Dreamweaver support for Handlebar and Mustache js?

Tags: editor, syntax-highlighting, handlebars.js, mustache

Is there any syntax highlighter for working on Handlebar js and Mustache js?

At this point Im using a different theme for Dreamweaver and it keeps showing a red background color when using some of the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Just for .moustache templates as far as I know:
https://github.com/nuket/userDefineLang_Mustache

Have to figure out a way to delmit them.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does perfect syntax highlighting for Handlebars and Mustache.